# .git directory does not appear as a directory on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I cannot cd into some of my .git directories on Windows.

Some of my repositories are fine.  The .git directory appears as you would expect in them:
`drwxrwx---+ 1 grandps Domain Users 0 Oct 11 15:42 .git`
I can `cd` into the .git directory, and `ls` it to see its contents.

In other repos, the .git directory shows up as a regular file.  I can't `cd` into it or `ls` to see its contents. If I try to open it in Windows Explorer, I can't - Windows thinks it's a file, too.
`-rwxrwx---+ 1 grandps Domain Users   68 Jun 22 12:22 .git`

The repo still works as a git repository.  I can run git commands just fine.  I just can't get into the `.git` folder.

I have tried both Git Bash (MinGW64) and Cygwin.  Both give the same results.

Any ideas how this could have happened, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is the repository in question a sub module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation, the file should contain path to the actual repository directory.

> Also you can have a plain text file .git at the root of your working tree, containing gitdir:  to point at the real directory that has the repository. This mechanism is often used for a working tree of a submodule checkout, to allow you in the containing superproject to git checkout a branch that does not have the submodule
>
> source: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout

Comment: That was it, thanks!  The repos with this issue were all extra worktrees in a repo that had multiple branches checked out into different working directories.  I was able to `cat` the `.git` file to see the path of the `.git` directory in the original worktree.